# Mute all applications except one on Android

Tags: android, notification, volume-control

I'm looking for an Android application that can mute the sound notifications of all applications except one.

E.g. on Windows 7 I can do this in two clicks:

[image: Windows 7 "Volume Mixer"]

I use a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2. Free is better.

Comment: Good luck, Franck! I hope I'm proven wrong, but AFAIK that's not possible (i.e. currently no solution; it might be doable technically, though) on Android. While you have different channels (for e.g. ringtone, notifications, multimedia), I've never seen a way to mute or adjust volume on a per-app base.

Comment: Oh, am I permitted to prove myself wrong? Would something like [App Volume](http://www.appbrain.com/app/droidamax.appvolumefree) be acceptable? Maybe [PerApp](http://www.appbrain.com/app/mobi.omegacentauri.PerApp) could achieve that with a *negative* volume boost? Looks like [AppConfig](http://www.appbrain.com/app/appconfig-free/fi.aarosoft.appconfig.free) is exactly capable of what you need (but requires root). Just updating [alternatives](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=183)...

Comment: Hi Franck.  I know this question is a bit old (and I doubt you are still using an S3!), but did any of Izzy's suggestions wind up working?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like **[DetoxDroid](https://github.com/flxapps/DetoxDroid)** could fit that bill. It's intended for "digital detoxing", and one of its features is a global DND mode ("mute all applications"). It lets you define exeptions ("…except one"), thus matching your requirements.

For now, it's not available at any store I know of, and APKs must be downloaded from Github and side-loaded. In a few days it should become available on F-Droid, though (I've just processed its merge request today). To get the required powers, you must grant it once the `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission via ADB – then it works fine.